# Can't add files to git in current directory anymore

Tags: git, macos, osx-lion

git seems to have suddenly gone a bit haywire on my machine.

```
chris-greenings-macbook-2:tankgame chris$ pwd
/Users/chris/Work/Tanks/Android/tanks/src/com/cmgresearch/tankgame
chris-greenings-macbook-2:tankgame chris$ ls
GL2JNIActivity.java     IKeyboardServices.java      Properties.java         SoundEngine.java_free
GL2JNILib.java          OrientationListener.java    Properties.java_free        TouchEvent.java
GL2JNIView.java         OrientationManager.java     SoundEngine.java
chris-greenings-macbook-2:tankgame chris$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
<snip>
#   modified:   ../../../../../../Android/tanks/src/com/cmgresearch/tankgame/GL2JNIView.java
<snip>
```

Why is it doing all the ../../../../../../.. when the changed file is in the current directory?

If I try and do git add GL2JNIView.java it ignores me and doesn't think there are any changes to commit.

If I add the full `../../../../../../Android/tanks/src/com/cmgresearch/tankgame/GL2JNIView.java` then I can commit the changes.

Even doing

`git add *.java`

Will not add the changed files.

I'm sure this used to work - and I haven't changed anything in my setup. Is there some settings that stops you using the current directory in git?

I'm running on macosx lion.

git version 1.7.5.4

Edit - rebooted the machine and now it's behaving as normal. Anyone have any ideas why it got into the funny state?

Comment: I've seen the same problem intermittently using git with cygwin-- sometimes it doesn't seem to resolve paths correctly when you are not at the repository root.  Interesting if there is a definitive answer to this.

Comment: Do you have a `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable set?

Comment: Nope no GIT_WORK_TREE in my environment

Comment: Sorry cd . does nothing. Problem persists.

Comment: Ok, problem gone. Rebooted the computer and it's behaving as normal.

The old switch it off and on again fixes all problems!

Comment: you would have had to cd ../../.. all the way to the top. The reboot did nothing more than to make you cd into the directory using the correct casing. Rebooting does not "fix" git repo issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check the casing in your path as you CD into it. This is what causes the issue. When entering each directory, tab complete the name. Git is case sensitive.

Hope this helps next time.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. If I'm in the current directory I don't need to enter any path names so there shouldn't be any case issues.

Comment: There are issues because casing makes it a different tree. To reproduce, don't do the correct casing as you CD in, stage all changes and see what happens when you run `git status`.